# Pointer to portions of array

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an object of `std::vector<std::array<double, 16>>`

```
vector entry    Data
[0]           - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
[1]           - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
[2]           - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
[...]         - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

This is intended to represent a 4x4 matrix in ravel format.

To not duplicate information I would like to create a pointer to extract a 3x3 from the above structure:
I have mathematical operations for the 3x3 structure (`std::array<double, 9>`)

`someStructure`: pointing to data elements `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 10]`

The end goal is do: `std::array<double, 9> tst = someStructure[0] + someStructure[1];`

Is this doable?

Best Regards

Comment: what is the relevance of the vector? A 4x4 matrix has only 16 elements and is represted by a single element of the vector, right?

Comment: Its to represent a block of matrices

Comment: yes I think I got that, but your question seems to be about operations on a single matrix, so maybe you can remove the vector

Comment: I would suggest you get yourself a matrix library.  There is no way to just get a pointer to a internal (nested) 3x3 matrix with the structure you have.

Comment: Your 3x3 matrix won't be a contiguous piece of memory, thus referencing aka `std::array<double, 9>` isn't really feasible

Comment: Here is less know [std::valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) which is capable to do something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3x3 part is not contiguous, hence a pointer alone wont help here.

You can write a `view_as_3x3` that allows you to access elements of the submatrix of the `4x4` as if it was contiguous:

```
struct view_as_3x3 {
    double& operator[](size_t index) {
        static const size_t mapping[] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10};
        return parent[mapping[index]];
    }
    std::array<double, 16>& parent;
};
```

Such that for example

```
for (size_t = 0; i< 9; ++i) std::cout << " " << view_as_3x3{orignal_matrix}[i];
```

is printing the 9 elements of the 3x3 sub-matrix of the original 4x4 `original_matrix`.

Then you could more easily apply your 3x3 algorithms to the 3x3 submatrix of a 4x4 matrix. You just need to replace the `std::array<double, 9>` with some generic `T`. For example change

```
double sum_of_elements(const std::array<double, 9>& arr) {
       double res = 0;
       for (int i=0;i <9; ++i) res += arr[i];
       return res;
}
```

To:

```
template <typename T>
double sum_of_elements(const T& arr) {
       double res = 0;
       for (int i=0;i <9; ++i) res += arr[i];
       return res;
}
```

The calls are then

```
 std::array<double, 16> matrix4x4;
 sum_of_elements(view_as_3x3{matrix4x4});
 // or
 std::array<double, 9> matrix3x3;
 sum_of_elements(matrix3x3);
```

It would be nicer to use iterators instead of indices, however, writing the view with custom iterators requires considerable amount of boilerplate. On the other hand, I would not suggest to use naked `std::array`s in the first place, but rather some `my_4x4matrix` that holds the array as member and provides iterators and more convenience methods.

Comment: If I  have operations defined for a 3x3 matrix, is it possible to declare the `view_as_3x3` structure as a 3x3 matrix and make it have all the operations available to the 3x3 matrix?

Comment: @ManuelOliveira the last part of the answer is about that. When your operations on the 3x3 matrix are written as generic algorithms (templates, or using iterators) then you can use them with either a `view_as_3x3` or a 3x3 matrix

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, when I run the code I get: `error: passing ‘const view_as_3x3’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`. I think there is `const` missing at the end of `double& operator[](size_t index)`  Additionally, there is a comma missing in mapping between the number 9 and 10.

Comment: @ManuelOliveira I fixed the missing `,`. The missing `const` is because the answer merely sketches the idea. A proper implementation should have a non-const and const overload (which would return a `const double&`)

Comment: ...and maybe there should be a `const_view` as well. Not sure whats the best design to handle both

Comment: Hello, a question. Any particular reason for the `static size_t` ? Won't a `const int[]` work as well ?

Comment: @ManuelOliveira yes it should be `const`, i fixed that. But indices into arrays can only be unsigned and `size_t` is the type to be used for indices. `int` would work as well, but its the wrong type