# Pointer to portions of array. Operations with filtered array

Tags: c++, c++11

Following the question in [Pointer to portions of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69677048/pointer-to-portions-of-array), a structure that does operations with portions of an array was proposed.

However, I am having a problem when calling functions that change entries in the matrices.

When defining operations for matrices it is standard to pass by reference. However, when I use the same structure for the filtered array I get:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘subMat&’ to an
> rvalue of type ‘subMat’

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// define matrix 4x4
typedef std::array<double, 16> matrix4;

// define matrix 3x3
typedef std::array<double, 9>  matrix3;

struct subMat{

    matrix4& matrix_;

    const double& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        static size_t mapping[] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10};
        return matrix_[mapping[index]];
    }
    double& operator[](size_t index)
{
    static size_t mapping[] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10};
    return matrix_[mapping[index]];
}


    subMat (matrix4& A): matrix_(A){}
};

template <typename T>
double sum_of_elements(const T& arr)
{
    double res = 0;
    for (int i=0;i <9; ++i) res += arr[i];
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
void test(T& arr)
{
    for (int i=0;i <9; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = 1;
    } 
}


int main(int argCount, char *args[])
{
    std::vector<matrix4> myBlockMatrix(5);

    for (int i=0; i < myBlockMatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<myBlockMatrix[0].size(); j++)
        {
            myBlockMatrix[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<myBlockMatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << sum_of_elements(subMat(myBlockMatrix[i])) << std::endl; // this owrks
    }

    test(subMat(myBlockMatrix[0])); // this does not work

    subMat a = subMat(myBlockMatrix[0]); 
    test(a); // this works and changes the values in myBlockMatrix

    return 0;
}
```

The question is: What can I do with this structure to re-use the previous functions for `matrix3`. Do I need to always create a new instance of `subMat` to do operations? Or is there a way to use `subMat(myBlockMatrix[0])` inside the function argument?

Comment: Unless you are doing this for learning, take a look at `std::val_array<T>` which provides much more than what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.
For the time being, this is to learn C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message: Your `test` function takes an **l**value reference but the *temporary* `subMat` object constructed as the argument in the `test(subMat(myBlockMatrix[0]))` call is an **r**value.

The simplest fix for this is to redeclare the `test` function template to have a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) argument:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void test(T&& arr) // forwarding reference
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

This will allow the compiler to create versions of `test` that take either lvalue *or* rvalue references, the latter being used in the case when the argument is a temporary object.

From the linked cppreference page:

> Rvalue references can be used to extend the lifetimes of temporary
> objects (note, lvalue references to const can extend the lifetimes of
> temporary objects too, but they are not modifiable through them).

Comment: That is one solution,  but it will not allow me to re-use my functions for `matrix3`. I would have to redefine the functions to take rvalues in the argument

Comment: @ManuelOliveira Not sure what you mean. (1) `test` is declared as a function *template*. (2) There's nothing I can see in your code that uses the `matrix3` class.

Comment: In short, I will have to change the function arguments and that is not desirable