# Pointer to portions of array. Overloading [] operator to access portions of array

Tags: c++, c++11

Following the question in [Pointer to portions of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69677048/pointer-to-portions-of-array), a structure that does operations with portions of an array was proposed.

I would like to request one further question within this issue.

I would like to create a structure for blockMatrices using `std::vector` and would require to change the implementation of the structure for getting a 3x3 matrix out of a 4x4 matrix.

The current test case is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// define matrix 4x4
typedef std::array<double, 16> matrix4;

// define matrix 3x3
typedef std::array<double, 9>  matrix3;

// get 3x3 matrix out of a 4x4 matrix
struct subMat
{
    matrix4& matrix_;

    const double& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        static size_t mapping[] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10};
        return matrix_[mapping[index]];
    }    
    subMat (matrix4& A): matrix_(A){}
};

template <typename T>
double sum_of_elements(const T& arr)
{
    double res = 0;
    for (int i=0;i < 9; ++i)
    {
        res += arr[i];
    } 
    return res;
}

int main(int argCount, char *args[])
{
    std::vector<matrix4> myBlockMatrix(5);

    for (int i=0; i < myBlockMatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<myBlockMatrix[0].size(); j++)
        {
            myBlockMatrix[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<myBlockMatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << sum_of_elements(subMat(myBlockMatrix[i])) << std::endl; // this works
    }

    subBlockMatrix subBlock (myBlockMatrix);
    for (int i = 0; i<myBlockMatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << sum_of_elements(subBlock[i])) << std::endl; 
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

For overloading the `[]` operator, I have:

```
struct subBlockMatrix : std::vector<matrix4>
{
    std::vector<matrix4>& blockMatrix_;

    const matrix4& operator[](std::size_t index) const
    {   
        static size_t mapping[] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10};
        return blockMatrix_[mapping[index]];
    } 
    subBlockMatrix(std::vector<matrix4>& A) : blockMatrix_(A) {}
};
```

But this does not work...
I am having difficulty understanding how to make it work and would really appreciate the help!

Best Regards

Comment: The inheritance is suspicious.

Comment: *"But this does not work..."*? Which mean? compilation issue (so Which is the error message), wrong behavior (so which is the expected and current result).

Comment: @Jarod42, that I can answer. The outcome of the second and third for loop is expected to be the same (it should the same indices): 0, 45, 90, 135, 180. But the output values are: 0, 36, 72, 108, 144

Comment: With `return blockMatrix_[mapping[index]];`, you change access for the vector, not the `matrix4` (you might want `subMat operator[](std::size_t index) const { return subMat(blockMatrix_[index]); }`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a matrix view, which starts with an array view.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class Size=std::size_t, class Stride=Size>
struct array_view {
  array_view( T* start, Size sz, Stride s ):
    b(start), length(sz), stride(s) {}
  array_view( T* start, Size sz = {} ):
    b(start), length(sz), stride(sz) {}
  array_view() = default;
  array_view( T* start, T* finish ):
    array_view(start, finish-start) {}
 
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return b+length; }
  std::size_t size() const { return length; }
  bool empty() const { return size() == 0; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return b; }

  T& operator[]( std::size_t i ) const { return begin()[i]; }

  array_view& operator++() {
    *this += 1;
    return *this;
  }
  array_view operator++(int)& {
    auto self = *this;
    ++this;
    return self;
  }
  array_view& operator--() {
    *this -= 1;
    return *this;
  }
  array_view operator--(int)& {
    auto self = *this;
    --this;
    return self;
  }

  array_view& operator+=(std::ptrdiff_t delta)&{
    b+=delta*length;
    return *this;
  }
  array_view& operator-=(std::ptrdiff_t delta)&{
    b-=delta*length;
    return *this;
  }
  friend array_view operator+(array_view self, std::ptrdiff_t delta) {
    self += delta;
    return self;
  }
  friend array_view operator-(array_view self, std::ptrdiff_t delta) {
    self -= delta;
    return self;
  }
  friend array_view operator+(std::ptrdiff_t delta, array_view self) {
    self += delta;
    return self;
  }
  friend array_view operator-(std::ptrdiff_t delta, array_view self) {
    self -= delta;
    return self;
  }

  // checks address, not contents
  friend bool operator==(array_view const& lhs, array_view const& rhs) {
    return lhs.b == rhs.b && lhs.length == rhs.length && lhs.stride == rhs.stride;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(array_view const& lhs, array_view const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
private:
  T* b = nullptr;
  Size length = {};
  Stride stride = {};
};
```

then we get a matrix_view.  First we write an `index_iterator` for an iterator wrapper around something that is a value (like a sequence of rows or columns, or an integer):

```
template<class V>
struct index_iterator {
  index_iterator(V v):value(v) {}

  V const& operator*() const& { return value; }
  V& operator*()& { return value; }
  V operator*()&& { return std::move(value); }

  V* operator->() { return std::addressof(value); } 
  V const* operator->() const { return std::addressof(value); }

  friend bool operator==(index_iterator const& lhs, index_iterator const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.value==rhs.value;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(index_iterator const& lhs, index_iterator const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.value!=rhs.value;
  }

  index_iterator& operator++() {
    ++value;
    return *this;
  }
  index_iterator operator++(int)& {
    auto self = *this;
    ++value;
    return self;
  }
  index_iterator& operator--() {
    --value;
    return *this;
  }
  index_iterator operator--(int)& {
    auto self = *this;
    --value;
    return self;
  }

  index_iterator& operator+=( std::ptrdiff_t delta )& {
    value += delta;
    return *this;
  }
  index_iterator& operator-=( std::ptrdiff_t delta )& {
    value -= delta;
    return *this;
  }
  friend index_iterator operator+(index_iterator self, std::ptrdiff_t delta) {
    self += delta;
    return self;
  }
  friend index_iterator operator-(index_iterator self, std::ptrdiff_t delta) {
    self -= delta;
    return self;
  }
  friend index_iterator operator+(std::ptrdiff_t delta, index_iterator self) {
    self += delta;
    return self;
  }
  friend index_iterator operator-(std::ptrdiff_t delta, index_iterator self) {
    self -= delta;
    return self;
  }

  V operator[](std::size_t i)const {
    return *((*this) + i);
  }
private:
  V value = {};
};

template<class T, class M=std::size_t, class Stride=M, class N=M>
struct matrix_view {
  using row_view = array_view<T, N, Stride>;

  matrix_view( T* start, M cols={}, Stride stride = {}, N rows={} ):
    b(start), m(cols), s(stride), n(rows)
  {}
  matrix_view() = default;
 
  index_iterator<row_view> begin() const { return {{b, n, s}}; }
  index_iterator<row_view> end() const { return begin()+m; }
  std::size_t size() const { return m; }
  bool empty() const { return size() == 0; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return b; }

  row_view operator[]( std::size_t i ) const { return begin()[i]; }
  
private:
  T* b = nullptr;
  M m = {};
  Stride s = {};
  N n = {};
};
template<std::size_t N>
using size = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;


int main(){
  std::vector<int> v {00,01,02,03, 10,11,12,13, 20,21,22,23, 30,31,32,33};
  matrix_view<int, size<3>, size<4>> m = v.data()+5;
  for (auto col:m) {
    for (auto e:col) {
      std::cout << e << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

and then clean it up with some CRTP DRY and EBO.

But that is just me.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/bePYv4d7r).